# Как получить значение value из тега li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Решил заменить чекбоксы с помощью списка ul и стилизовать. В итоге столкнулся с проблемой.

**Как взять data-attr значение из списка li ?**

И если выбрать другой li, то выберется соответствующий data-attr.

Пробовал эти варианты, но там почему-то берется только первый li и больше не переключается:

```
function costCalculator() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('area').value) + 1;
}
```

и

```
function costCalculator() { 
  result.innerHTML = parseInt(area.value) + $('.rooms.active').attr('data-attr');
}
```

\
\
\
\

**Песочница для экспериментов:**
https://jsfiddle.net/Mesuti/5kugx8j6/5/

```
  <ul id="room">
      <li class="rooms active" data-attr="5">1 комнатная</li>
      <li class="rooms" data-attr="10">2 комнатная</li>
      <li class="rooms" data-attr="15">3 комнатная</li>
    </ul>

<input id="area" type="text" value="1" placeholder="Введите площадь">

    <h2>Результат: </h2>
    <span id="result"></span>
```

**// Математика Input + Data-attr. ВМЕСТО XXXXXXX НУЖНО ВЗЯТЬ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ LI. ЕСЛИ ВЫБИРАТЬ ДРУГОЙ LI, ТО ЗНАЧЕНИЕ МЕНЯЕТСЯ.**

```
function costCalculator() { 
result.innerHTML = parseInt(area.value) + XXXXXXX;
}
```

Comment: У тега `li` не может быть `value`

Comment: И кстати не плохо было бы получить внятный вопрос, чего хотелось бы добиться... 10 раз прочитал не понял...

Comment: @Air, сегодня явно не ваш день

Comment: @Pavel,  )))) пророк....

Comment: @АлександрСорокин, значение атрибута это **всегда** строка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтобы значение из data-attr складывалось со значением площади area необходимо привести значение к числу с помощью parseInt():

```
parseInt($('.rooms.active').attr('data-attr'))
```

Кроме того при переходе на следующую вкладку необходимо делать пересчет, т.е. вызывать функцию `costCalculator` по клику на вкладке.

```js
$('#kvart').click(function() {
  $('#area').fadeOut(100, function () {
     $('#room').fadeIn('100'); 
  });
}); 

$('#house').click(function() {
  $('#room').fadeOut(100, function () {
     $('#area').fadeIn('100'); 
  });
}); 

$('#kommerc').click(function() {
  $('#room').fadeOut(100, function () {
     $('#area').fadeIn('100'); 
  });
}); 

$('#home').on('click', 'li', function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});

$('#room').on('click', 'li', function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    costCalculator();
});


function onInput() {
 costCalculator();
}

// Математика Input + Data-attr 
function costCalculator() { 
result.innerHTML = parseInt(area.value) + parseInt($('.rooms.active').attr('data-attr'));
}

document.getElementById('area').addEventListener('input', onInput);
```

```css
.characteristic {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

.characteristic li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: #F03226 solid 1px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  color: #606060;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.characteristic li:hover {
    background-color: #F03226;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.active {
    background-color: #F03226;
    color: white !important;
}

#area {
  border: #F03226 solid 1px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  color: #606060;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#area:active, #area:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.dn {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="home" class="characteristic dn">
  <li id="kvart">Квартира</li>
  <li id="house">Дом</li>
  <li id="kommerc">Коммерческие помещения</li>
</ul>

<ul id="room" class="characteristic">
  <li class="rooms active" data-attr="5">1 комнатная</li>
  <li class="rooms" data-attr="10">2 комнатная</li>
  <li class="rooms" data-attr="15">3 комнатная</li>
</ul>

<input id="area" class="characteristic" type="text" value="1" placeholder="Введите площадь">

<h2>Результат: </h2>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: все верно, у вас ошибка в коде в том, что result у вас неопределен. Я добавил рабочий пример на основе вашего jsfiddle выше

Comment: а сам data-attr вы верно запрашивали

Comment: @Pavel, а этом случае result брался из глобального объекта, так как в некоторых браузерах доступ к элементам может быть напрямую по `id`. Поэтому при обращении к `result` шло обращение к `<span id="result">` Из-за этого result не был `undefined`

Comment: @Pavel, кроме того, предоставленный сниппет работает неверно.

Comment: Обновил только что

Comment: Не хватает описания решения. То что сейчас - не относится к вопросу. А только сниппет никак не поясняет в чем была проблема

Comment: @Pavel, без описания, никто не узнает что эти _косяки_ вообще были, и что они как-то решены.

Comment: Первые два абзаца никак не относятся к вопросу, так как `result` - **определен**.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Задали направление, для изучения данной ситуации.

Comment: 1. Добавили вызов функции калькулятора в функцию нажатия элемента списка. 
2. Добавили parseIn в сложении 
3. Определили span id="result"
Спасибо за участие!